# RemoteWebDriver throws = SessionNotCreatedException : Unable to create session from org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload@57ab6ec1

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, opera, selenium-grid

I'm trying to run a test using Opera browser as a node, hub and node connections are succesful.

Below is for hub and node connections:

Hub > `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar -role hub`

Node > `java -Dwebdriver.opera.driver=C:\zip\exe\operadriver_win64\operadriver_win64\operadriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.1.10:4444/grid/register -port 5566`

When trying to executing the program two Opera browser loads but only blank white pages shown with Not secure data:; on URL and I am also getting this kind of exception.

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session from org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload@6153fbda
```

Opera driver and Opera Browser I'm using:

Opera Version: 82.0.4227.58
Opera Driver Version : 96.0.4664.45

Below is the code used:

```
package Grid;

    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.*;
    
    
    public class OperaNode {
        
        static WebDriver driver;
        String nodeUrl;
        
    
        
    
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @BeforeTest
      public void OpenBrowser() throws InterruptedException {
          try {
              
    
                nodeUrl = "http://192.168.1.10:5566/wd/hub";
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.opera();
                capabilities.setBrowserName("opera");
                capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capabilities);
                driver.manage();
                driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
      @Test
      public void SigninButton() throws InterruptedException {
            try {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='_yb_duqkn']")).click();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
      @AfterTest
      public void CloseBrowser() {
          driver.quit();
      }
    
    }
```

Below is the console Message:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest OpenBrowser
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session from org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload@6153fbda
Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:42:28.403Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-KML9RV5', ip: '192.168.1.10', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '16.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 1.94 seconds
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
    at Grid.OperaNode.OpenBrowser(OperaNode.java:36)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:637)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:627)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:589)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session from org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload@6153fbda
Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:42:28.403Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-KML9RV5', ip: '192.168.1.10', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '16.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:42:28.403Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-KML9RV5', ip: '192.168.1.10', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '16.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$null$4(NewSessionPipeline.java:75)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$createNewSession$5(NewSessionPipeline.java:74)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.createNewSession(NewSessionPipeline.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession.execute(BeginSession.java:65)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.lambda$handle$0(WebDriverServlet.java:242)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RemoteWebDriver url configuration should always be routed to the hub, if using the Selenium Grid setup as your browser stack. The hub will then check for a node which matches your browser request and forward onto that node.

```
nodeUrl = "http://<hub ip address>:4444/wd/hub";
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.opera();
capabilities.setBrowserName("opera");
capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capabilities);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it resolved the issue, but there is a new exception came out:
'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: opera, platform: WINDOWS, version: }'